# .Net Core App 2.0 not compatible with .Net Standard 2.0 libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017, I created a solcution containing the following:

- ASP.Net Core web application project (ASP.Net MVC)
- two class library projects created as .Net Standard libraries

By default out of the box, VS 2017 makes these class libraries target .Net Standard 2.0, and the web application targets .Net Core 1.1.

Added project dependencies - the web app has both of the two class libraries as project dependencies (as they contain the core functionality, the web app being merely the front end).

Theoretically, VS should have chosen sensible defaults. However, that does not compile. I am getting errors like this:

```
Error   CS1705  
Assembly 'Entities' with identity 'Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.2.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version 
than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime, 
Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

I do not know how to change references to System.Runtime, and find no option in VS to do so.

Okay - .Net Core 1.1 *should* really not make sense with .Net Standard 2.0 (even though .Net Core 1.1 is not even listed in the official .Net Standard overview graphic, see [official MS Github documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md), so I how can we be sure?).

So let's change that and modify the target of the web app to .Net Core 2.0, so that everything targets 2.0 - per the above official chart that should dovetail just fine - so in VS with Projects > Properties we change the target framework to .Net Core 2.0, and rebuild solution.
(Note that my VS instance is set to restore Nuget packages on every rebuild as it is by default.)

Again does not work. Different errors this time - several errors of that kind here:

```
    Error   NU1605  Detected package downgrade: System.Net.Primitives from 4.3.0 
    to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a 
different version. 
     UI.Web (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink (>= 1.1.2) -> 
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions (>= 1.1.2) -> NETStandard.Library 
    (>= 1.6.1) -> System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.3.0) 
     UI.Web (>= 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink (>= 1.1.2) -> 
    System.Net.Primitives (>= 4.0.11)   UI.Web  C:\Source\Projects\Test
    \UI.Web\UI.Web.csproj
```

In earlier versions of the .Net Core tooling (VS 2015) there had been many JSON files allowing for tweaking of dependency versions but this no longer applies in VS 2017 - csproj is the only one and it's in XML and contains no reference to any of the packages listed above in the error.

So what does this mean? .Net Core 2.0 is not compatible with .Net Standard 2.0 libraries?

Funny thing is, it isn't the first time I have produced that kind of an app and just a few months ago, it worked right out of the box. Looking into an older app which works fine I find that

- the .Net standard libraries are on .Net Standard 1.6
- ASP.Net Core web app is on .Net Core 1.1

Changed that in my new project - and voila, it works.

But this raises still these questions:

1. Is .Net Core 2.0 is not compatible with .Net Standard 2.0 libraries?
2. Is that an issue in VS 2017 that the default frameworks for .Net Core
   and .Net Standard libraries do not dovetail, or is that something
   I can set up / configure?

Comment: Each of my .NET Core and .NET Standard applications have been built on either Ubuntu or MacOS, using the CLI tools and I haven't had this issue (I've used each of the builds from the initial public preview up to the RTM of 2.0.0). Perhaps it is an issue with VS 2017. Core 2.0 is fully compliant with Standard 2.0, so I don't think it's that. Which version of VS 2017 are you using?

Comment: I am using VS 2017 Community, version 15.3.0. Created a few  test projects just to test this issue, it happens every time.

Comment: Hmm... That is quite strange. I might try spinning up an Azure hosted VM and try to recreate. In the mean time, I wonder whether it's worth trying to update your VS instance. Head to Add & Remove programs in control panel, find VS and choose modify, let the installer update then update your installation.

Answer (score 2):

I was running into something similar when trying to build the auto-generated .NET Core 2.0 server stub from swagger.io web editor.

This helped for me:

1. Switched the target from .NET Core 2.0 to .NET Core 1.1
2. Tried to build, got other errors
3. Switched the target back to .NET Core 2.0

Just a workaround, yes, but it got me forward.

Answer (score 0):

To state the obvious, .NET Core 2.0 is .NET Standard 2.0 compliant.

However, you may see error/warning messages such as `NU1605 Detected package downgrade`. This happens as well when referencing `log4net 2.0.8` for instance.

`NU1605` is in fact a warning, however, by default it's treated as an error in Visual Studio 2017.

You can change this back to a warning by editing the csproj file (search for something like `<WarningsAsErrors>NU1605</WarningsAsErrors>`) or from Visual Studio go to project properties > Build > Treat Warnings as Errors.